# Is WSF / WSO2 compatible with ruby 1.9.3p0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wso2

I'm working with WSF here: http://wso2.org/project/wsf/ruby/1.1.0/docs/manual.html

The documentation cites 1.8.5 or above, but I'm running into issues with 1.9.3p0.  Can anyone confirm that this framework is incompatible with ruby 1.9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSF/Ruby framework can most probably be incompatible with 1.9.3p0. That statement of version 1.8.5 or higher is based on the assumption that WSF/Ruby will remain backward compatible. Since there is no active development on the project, any issues with later Ruby versions may not be fixed.